Is it still possible for me to speak/learn Japanese to a native-like level?
For context, l'm 13 and have very recently began learning Japanese. I'm very fascinated by the culture and history and plan to study abroad there-however this is where the title comes in. I've done a bit of web diving and have seen that it's harder to achieve native-like fluency and enunciation after around 10yrs. I've seen plenty of other people pick up other languages in adulthood, however is it still possible I can achieve native-like fluency (possibly without an accent) in Japanese or is it too late? Not into adulthood yet so wanted to ask, thanks.
Just to clarify, it's not stopping me from learning BUT it would be great if I could achieve native-like skills. Thanks.

Probably off-topic here, but maybe acceptable on https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/.

"Just to clarify, it's not stopping me from learning BUT it would be great if I could achieve native-like skills." - suppose we told you it's still possible; would that change your approach? If we told you it's not possible, would that change your approach? And who exactly is supposed to define "native-like"?

Yes, "native-like fluency" is nebulous. Even just "fluency" is not something everyone agrees on.

This question would be more suitable for the Language Learning SE. But in general, if you desire a level of "no accent", you would need to move to Japan now and attend school with Japanese people. If your goal is to be able to converse fluently without any issues, it’s never too late no matter how old.
